# how to connect to remote SQL Server Express over internet?

Tags: c#, sql-server, tcp

I have a Windows 10 PC with SQL Server Express, I have setup remote connections, allocated a fixed port (express, 22172, removed TCP Dynamic Ports under IPALL), set an inbound rule for the port etc.

I can connect and manipulate the database from a Linux PC on the same network (on the same LAN router), using:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = @"192.168.1.22\SQLEXPRESS, 22172";
builder.InitialCatalog = "<database>";
builder.ItegratedSecurity=  "sa";
builder.Password = "<password>"

string connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

So, the normal firewall inbound rules, remote connection settings etc work, correct? I now want to be able to make that same connection, from a Windows PC that is on a different internet (from a different location/town..)

I have:

- Acquired a fixed IP for the router that the host PC is on
- Fixed the
  host PC's local IP - 192.168.1.22 according to [this](https://portforward.com/networking/static-ip-windows-10.htm)
  link
- Set the IP under IP2 for "Protocols for SQLEXPRESS - TCP/IP - IP
  Addresses" to 192.168.1.22
- Added SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit as
  allowed app in firewall
- Enabled TCP/IP and Named Pipes in SQL Server
  Client Network Utility with Start - Run - CLICONFG.exe
- Set port
  forwarding on the router: Service Port 22172, IP Address:
  192.168.1.22, Internal Port 22172, Protocol - TCP, Enabled

I have switched off the firewall, and still get the error: "(provider: TCP Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I try these connection string options:

```
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = @"tcp:xxx.xxx.x.xx\SQLEXPRESS, 22172";
        builder.InitialCatalog = "<database>";
        builder.UserID = "sa";
        builder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        builder.Password = "<password>";

        sqlConnect = builder.ConnectionString;
```

I have also tried these variations:

```
        builder.DataSource = @"x.xxx.x.xx\SQLEXPRESS, 22172";
        builder.DataSource = @"tcp:xxx.xxx.x.xx, 22172";
        builder.DataSource = @"xxx.xxx.x.xx, 22172";
```

Also these connection strings:

```
        sqlConnect = @"Data Source = tcp:xxx.xxx.x.xx\SQLEXPRESS,22172; Initial Catalog = <database>; User ID = sa; Password = <password>";
        sqlConnect = @"Data Source = xxx.xxx.x.xx\SQLEXPRESS,22172; Initial Catalog = <database>; User ID = sa; Password = <password>";
        sqlConnect = @"Data Source = tcp:xxx.xxx.x.xx,22172; Initial Catalog = <database>; User ID = sa; Password = <password>";
        sqlConnect = @"Data Source = xxx.xxx.x.xx,22172; Initial Catalog = <database>; User ID = sa; Password = <password>";
```

And for good measure, this one:

```
sqlConnect = @"Data Source=xxx.xxx.x.xx\SQLEXPRESS,22172;Initial Catalog=<database>;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=<password>;";
```

I have scanned all relevant questions on SO etc - somewhere I am doing something small wrong?  Please help

Output when running `select * from sys.tcp_endpoints` on host PC SQL: Thus, ip_address is NULL for both, port is 0 for both, and is_dynamic_port is 1 for both - is that the relevant information?

```
Dedicated Admin Connection  1   1   2   TCP 2   TSQL    0   STARTED 1   0   1   NULL
TSQL Default TCP            4   1   2   TCP 2   TSQL    0   STARTED 0   0   1   NULL
```

I have tried several times to change the dynamic port to static, I have removed all 0 or port numbers in configuration manager, but still get a 1 for _is_dynamic_port.  Event Viewer shows:

```
Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 22172].
```

Same message if I run the following in SQL:

```
EXEC xp_ReadErrorLog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on', N'any', NULL, NULL, 'DESC'
```

GO

Why does SQL settings remain on dynamic ports?

Comment: Sounds like you need port forwarding on your edge router. The correct connection string is `xxx.xxx.x.xx,22172` but the relevant IP address would be the one for the edge router if you are connecting from a different LAN. You could also use dynamic DNS, to avoid having to get a static IP for it

Comment: as mentioned, I am doing port forwarding. And using the edge router's IP address to make the connection

Comment: What are the results of `select * from sys.tcp_endpoints` ?

Comment: @lptr please see updated detail in question

Comment: ..it seems the named instance is running on a dynamic port. Once you set it to fixed 22172 port..and you are able to connect to the instance by using “192.168.1.22, 22172" (from the win or linux machine)..then after port_forwarding on the router..it should be possible to connect using internetIP,22172. You could also disable the firewall on the windows host of the sql instance for a brief time, during connection testing.

Comment: I have tried several times to change the dynamic port to static, I have removed all 0 or port numbers in configuration manager, but still get a 1 for _is_dynamic_port

Comment: the tcp_endpoints are not relevant for the port settings in configuration manager. It is just a step for checking if anyone configured an endpoint to the port. If yoo can connect to the instance by using “192.168.1.22, 22172" (no instance name, just: ip,port) then the settings in configuration manager are correct.

Comment: any settings further I can check?  all correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your ISP does not block ports / all ports. That is what stopped me.

Comment: you didn't quit. And found it. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

From your work, I suppose you set it all on the Win PC.
So,...

1. What about the Linux machine? Does it allow to do outbound connections to 192.168.1.22?
2. Tak a look at the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity`. It should have a bool value. `false` if user and password should be used for the authentication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.integratedsecurity?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).
3. Tak a look at the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder.UserID`. It is missing in both of your code snippets. But mentioned at created connection strings `Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=<password>;` as «User ID», «user» и «uid». Please, see here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.userid?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

Comment: 1. Yes the Linux machine can connect (outbound) connection to the host windows PC 192.168.1.22.
2. Integrated security is included in the stringbuilder (it is equal to "sa" for the linux machines's connection string, which works). 3 I added the userId, still the same error

Comment: K. 'Outer' issues handled. Then what about your named instance? Does it have 'SQLEXPRESS' as its name? Is it running? If it is running then update the pipe name to make it the same everywhere.

Comment: yes it is SQLEXPRESS, running?  yes on automatic and always starts up with PC startup.  Why update the pipe name, and if so, where to update?

Comment: got your recent update on the topic. Yes, not 22172 port could be the source issue. Default MSSQL port is 1433. "TCP Dynamic Ports under IPALL" means "any dynamic port" (not listed exact ports). In the IPALL section, there should be a "TCP Port" row. That row should have your 22172 port to run only at the specified port.

Comment: I have TCP Port as 22172 under IPALL, any other ideas?  should I choose a different port number?

Comment: No, I ran out of ideas. Sorry. 8\

Comment: after moving on to SSH, and much struggling again.. it turns out that the ISP blocks all ports, whether you forward on the router or not... the APN is not unrestricted and they, apparently, do not offer such services! africa!